# How to group by day and then count by a specific category?

Tags: r

My test dataset

```
Date        Fruit
01/01/2021  Apple
01/01/2021  Apple
01/01/2021  Lemon
02/01/2021  Lemon
03/01/2021  Peach
03/01/2021  Apple
```

I require to group by date and then count by each type of fruit, so The resulting dataframe should look something like this

```
Date         Apple   Lemon  Peach
01/01/2021   2       1      0
02/01/2021   0       1      0
03/01/2021   1       0      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your data frame is, `d`:

```
table(d$Date, d$Fruit)
            
 #            Apple Lemon Peach
 # 01/01/2021     2     1     0
 # 02/01/2021     0     1     0
 # 03/01/2021     1     0     1
```

And if you want to save this as data frame object:

```
dd = data.frame(unclass(table(d$Date, d$Fruit)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = df %>%  count (as.Date(Date), Fruit) %>%
              pivot_wider(names_from = Fruit, values_from = n)
```

Comment: You can pass `values_fill = 0` as an argument to `pivot_wider` to get 0's instead of NA's.